# EventMachine Channel - get subscribers count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine, subscriber

How to get an amount of subscribers for specific `EventMachine::Channel` to know that no subscribers are left and I can remove the channel?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way of getting this information - the subscribers is a private hash that doesn't have a public accessor method (see the source [here](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/channel.rb#L16)). I've got a [pull request](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/pull/640) open to add this functionality, in the meantime it's pretty straightforward to extend the Channel class to add it yourself.

Comment: I hacked into object and made a public property.